# Display videos in web site

Tags: c#

I had soluation of displaying video on my company site and my manager told me to add all videos in web site as list and didvid it list to (recent videos,most view,) pleas I want any one help me how can I do this?

note see this link
http://www.yallakora.com/arabic/YKChampions/EmbedListing.aspx?region=

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question so we can understand it better. Are you already able to post videos on your site? You seem to be asking for many things here. Try thinking of the smallest change that you need to make to your current functionality to get to your end goal and ask how to do that.

Comment: I think what he is trying to say, is how he can implement a way to list he's video's into two categories eg. Most Recent | Most Viewed. I'm guessing there may more categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your sorting order as a combination of # of views or last seen date or a weighted/filtered combination of the two factors. Essentially once you can write it on paper the sorting you want it is trivial after that

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you are storing Video information into some DB/flat file.

Now along with the video information you will have to save the `date when the video was added` and `ViewCount` this is to be incremented each time that video is being viewed.

Now to show Most recent you can simply pick up the videos with descending order of the date they were added. To show most viewed pick up videos with descending order of their ViewCount